# Set Bootstrap 3 unresponsive for IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3

it's possible to set the layout of bootstrap 3 in IE8 not responsive as in version 2 using respond.min.js without writing a special css for IE ?

```
<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>

    <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Practically speaking, no.

Answer (score 0):

Using respond.js is not making  responsive bootsrap layout in IE8.

You can check it on
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

You can read about respond.js on github:
https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/blob/master/README.md

The goal of this script is to provide a fast and lightweight (3kb minified / 1kb gzipped) script to enable responsive web designs in browsers that don't support CSS3 Media Queries - in particular, Internet Explorer 8 and under. It's written in such a way that it will probably patch support for other non-supporting browsers as well (more information on that soon).